# Recommended instance type when using pgrouting in AWS

Tags: pgrouting, amazon-web-services

Some advice required please.

When choosing instances in AWS (amazon web services) I can have a 'compute optimised' or 'memory optimised' instance. Can anyone recommend the best to use with pgrouting?

I am using pgrouting 2.4.2 with PostgreSQL 9.6.6

Comment: There are a number of variables that go into instance type selection for any purpose. Determining another's requirements with so little information about the size of the datatset, the volume of calculations, the required processing speed, and the cost tolerance is pure opinion. Heck, even with all those things, it's *still* probably too *opinion-based* for GIS SE, but without them there's really no way to start.